# How to programmatically use Zsh for autocomplete?

Tags: zsh

Zsh has awesome autocompletion. When I type `~/c/m` then hit tab, I get `~/code/meteor`. I love that. I'm building another application and I want to use this fuzzy autocompletion, but i don't know how to do it without actually typing tab.

Ideally, I could do something like this:

```
autocomplete "~/c/m"
```

And it will return `~/code/meteor`.

Any ideas how I can do this? I don't want to use fzf or some external installable program.

Comment: Sound like a good idea. Any particular language you want to implement it in? For use on the command line or in a script?

Comment: The best keywords to google here are `capture zsh completion`. Indeed an interesting undertaking but probably very hard since the output of the completion system is geared towards interactive use in a tty. You probably will need to run `zsh -i` in a pseudo-tty, send keystrokes and react to output. [Valodim@github](https://github.com/Valodim/zsh-capture-completion) made a proof-of-concept how to do this and it gets [messy quickly](https://github.com/Valodim/zsh-capture-completion/blob/master/capture.zsh#L72).

Comment: I figure bash or zsh would be fine. python would work too I suppose. I just want a clean solution. its all happening right there already, and its frustrating i can't just use that function! I'll keep looking with those keywords. looks like this guy was [pulling his hair out too](https://github.com/Valodim/zsh-capture-completion/blob/master/capture.zsh#L85), lol